# protractor 4 : how to locate a parent at 'n' level above by class

Tags: protractor

For instance with following html:

```
<div class='parent'>
  <p>
    <span class='child'></span>
  </p>
</div>
```

To locate .parent from .child I'm trying something like :

```
let child = element(by.css('.child'));
let parent = child.element(by.xpath('../..')); // not working
let parent = child.element(by.xpath('ancestor::.parent')); // not working
```

What's the best way to achieve that?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You have mentioned incorrect locator combination. That is incuded css value '.parent' in xpath expression. The right way is:

```
   let parent = child.element(by.xpath('ancestor::div')); 
OR 
   let parent = child.element(by.xpath('ancestor::div[1]'));
```